# How to check Returned Server Code Using DOM?

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am getting data from a REST based web service outputting data in XML format.
As I am using DOM and later parsing it to a `doc` using the `DocumentBuilder` I am not able to get the server's `HTTP Status Code` if there is any error.

So, is it Possible to return the `HTTP Status Code`?

Here is a little snippet:

```
url = "MY_URL";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Any advice is much appreciable. 

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by ***returned server code***?

Comment: My bad. It's the `Response Code` :D

Comment: it's pretty obvious ... 200, 404 ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467848/how-to-get-http-response-code-for-a-url-in-java

Comment: Response code of successful web service call or code returned by webservice?

Comment: AFAIK, response code is basically "the code returned from a server". Like Selvin has given above^ 404,200, 805. Moreover you can say the `HTTP Status Code` :D Please see my updated ques.

Comment: @Selvin so..I'll have to change* a few lines.. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a bit changes in your code to do so:

```
URL url = new URL("MY_URL");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(connection.getInputStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
int code = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Selvin had pointed the exact same in the comments..but as you're the first to put it here as "Answer". +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

url.openStream() will throw an IOException indicating the error if some problem occurs. Check the exception message/cause for details of the error.

Comment: That'd be not feasible per se. Had to change only a few line so :| Thanks anyway +1 :D