# JSoup + Link extraction + redirect URL

Tags: jsoup

My code works for most cases. It fails when the site redirects to a new URL. For example the URL: *http://www.oil-india.com/* redirects to *http://www.oil-india.com/oilnew/* in the browser. With JSoup the below code fails to retrieve links from the original URL.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).userAgent(USER_AGENT).validateTLSCertificates(false).followRedirects(true).get();

Elements subLinks = doc.select("a[href]");
```

Comment: Check a response code to do your condition [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467848/how-to-get-http-response-code-for-a-url-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print out the document you will notice, that the redirect is done using javascript:

```
[...]
window.location.href = '../oilnew/'; 
[...]
```

You could parse the script tag manually and when finding `window.location.href` either check if it is triggered on load and extract the target or use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) (though it is quite slow) to follow the redirects.

**Example Code**

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36";
String url = "http://www.oil-india.com/";

Document doc;
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

try {
    url = webClient.getPage(url).getUrl().toString(); // HtmlUnit
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent).followRedirects(true).get(); // jsoup
    System.out.println(doc.toString());
} catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Output**

```
<a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
<a href="default.aspx"><img src="oilindia-img/logo.jpg" alt="Oil India" style="height:95px;"></a>
 <a href="screenreader.aspx"><img src="oilindia-img/screen_reader_icon.png" style="vertical-align:middle;" alt="top"><span id="MenuBarTop_link_screenreader" class="link_screenreader">Screen Reader Access</span> </a>
<a href="javascript:decreaseFontSize();" class="toplink"> <img alt="orange color" src="oilindia-img/a-.png" id="Img1"> </a>
[...]
```