# Ho do I know if a post request has been successful

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am making a post request to this endpoint `http://httpbin.org/post` which should return the post I make, which would be  `String data = "something to post";` but I don't know if the post request has been successful. How can I find out?

Here the code I am using:

```
public class Post extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String urlString = "http://httpbin.org/post"; // URL to call

        Log.d("Blyat", urlString);

        String data = "something to post"; //data to post
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            Log.d("Post", String.valueOf(url));

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            Log.d("Post", String.valueOf(out));

            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            out.close();

            urlConnection.connect();
            Log.d("Post", String.valueOf(urlConnection));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        String algo = "blure";
        return algo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good implementation.  You can tell the success or failure by looking at HTTP response codes from the server.  I would recommend a client library written by someone else.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467848/how-to-get-http-response-code-for-a-url-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing on a OutputStream from a URLConnection you must then check for the status code from the connection object.

```
int statusCode = connection.getStatusCode();
```

if success ( == 200) then you can read the response by getting it from the InputStream of the Connection.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(connection.getInputStream());
```

From the response you will usually convert to string such:

```
        is = connection.getInputStream();
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        String response =  writer.toString();// have the body from response as String
```